# Difference and use of Array.Copy, CopyTo, and assignment of array in C#

Tags: c#

What is the difference between below three and their use, examples will be most preferable :

1. `sourceArray.CopyTo(targetArray, 0);`
2. `Array.Copy(sourceArray, targetArray, 0);`
3. `int []targetArray = sourceArray;`

Comment: [https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,d3c9a3da4e5d9327](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,d3c9a3da4e5d9327)

Comment: [https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1a86a6b8b02d0948](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1a86a6b8b02d0948)

Comment: Hey Chandan, it seems like the information you are asking for is very easily found using google, that is why your question got downvoted, and why you were commented with links to the microsoft reference source.

Answer (score 4):

The first two are almost identical and the last is pointing to the same reference.  See below:

1. `sourceArray.CopyTo(targetArray, 0);` simply calls `Array.Copy(sourceArray, targetArray, 0);` internally.
2. `Array.Copy(sourceArray, targetArray, 0);` is one of multiple overloaded static methods for copying elements of one array to elements of another array.
3. `int[] targetArray = sourceArray;` is giving `targetArray` the same reference as `sourceArray`.  Meaning; if you change `targetArray`'s array you're also changing the array referenced by `sourceArray` because they are the same (unless or until those references are reassigned to something else)

Comment: At point `3.`, if you change a value in `sourceArray`, `targetArray` will reflect the change. But (just something that might sound awkward to someone), if you set `sourceArray` to `null`, `targetArray` is still alive and kicking.

Comment: @Jimi Exactly... It's important to realize the difference between mutating your object and assigning / reassigning variables.